# Is it possible to use a wildcard in a directory name in wget for ftp?

Tags: ftp, wildcard, wget

I'm sorry if this has been answered already, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I need to download files from an ftp server that are inside a structure that looks like this:

ftp://ftp.some.adress/one/first_wildcard/two/second_wildcard/three/

I tried using * as a wildcard but it's not working:

```
wget -r -np -nd --accept='myfile*.ext' ftp://ftp.some.adress/one/*/two/*/three/
```

When I try this I get the error

> ERROR 404: Not Found.

This doesn't happen if I specify the exact names for the directories. If I put the entire path the file downloads without a problem, which is why I'm guessing the problem is in the *. Needless to say I don't want to specify the name one by one, since there are many directories.

I also tried adding `--glob=on` (because I have no idea what I'm doing) but the result is the same.

In case you need to see the ftp, here's the one I'm working with. User: anonymous, no password.

ftp://ftp.cccma.ec.gc.ca/data/climdex/CMIP5/historical/

and this works for me:

```
wget -r -np -nd --accept='prcptot*.nc' ftp://ftp.cccma.ec.gc.ca/data
/climdex/CMIP5/historical/ACCESS1-0/r1i1p1/v1/base_1961-1990/ --glob=on
```

And the wildcards should be in the place of **ACCESS1-0** and **v1**, i.e. doing the same thing for every directory available in those levels.

Any suggestion to make this work or to achieve the same goal with another tool (ftp, lftp, something else)?

Comment: No you cannot use wildcards in a middle of a path. I'm not even aware of any common FTP client that would support this.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I see. Is there maybe a way to retrieve the directory structure without the files? So I can maybe make a list out of the directories/subdirectories names and then download them in a loop in shell?

Comment: No there's no way in FTP protocol to retrieve directory structure without files. You have to list all entries in `/one/`, filter out the subfolders and iterate them and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works for me